# How can I download apps from the App Store without using Touch ID?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, touch-id

I can no longer install any apps from the App Store to my iPhone as the only way to now do so is via Touch ID which I cannot use on my phone. How can I download apps from the App Store without using Touch ID?

Comment: I'm really surprised it's not smart enough to just show you the passcode keypad. (:

Answer (score 5):

Go to the Settings app, then to Touch ID & Passcode. Enter your passcode, then turn off Touch ID for everything.